# Extract a list of files with a certain criteria within subdirectory of zip archive in python

Tags: python, path, zip, extract, glob

I want to access some .jp2 image files inside a zip file and create a list of their paths. The zip file contains a directory folder named `S2A_MSIL2A_20170420T103021_N0204_R108_T32UNB_20170420T103454.SAFE` and I am currently reading the files using glob, after having extracted the folder.

I don't want to have to extract the contents of the zip file first. I read that I cannot use glob within a zip directory, nor I can use wildcards to access files within it, so I am wondering what my options are, apart from extracting to a temporary directory.

The way I am currently getting the list is this:

```
dirr = r'C:\path-to-folder\S2A_MSIL2A_20170420T103021_N0204_R108_T32UNB_20170420T103454.SAFE'

jp2_files = glob.glob(dirr + '/**/IMG_DATA/**/R60m/*B??_??m.jp2', recursive=True)
```

There are additional different .jp2 files in the directory, for which reason I am using the glob wildcards to filter the ones I need.

I am hoping to make this work so that I can automate it for many different zip directories. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you want in a few lines using the [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) modules. Use `ZipFile.namelist()`.

Comment: Thanks, for your comment. I just managed to do it with zipfile and fnmatch.

Comment: Cool. Submit an answer then. Others people in the future might have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work with [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html) and [fnmatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html)

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import fnmatch
zip = path_to_zip.zip

with ZipFile(zipaki, 'r') as zipObj:
    file_list = zipObj.namelist()
    pattern = '*/R60m/*B???60m.jp2'

    filtered_list = []
    for file in file_list:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern):
            filtered_list.append(file)
```